# Фигурные скобки при выводе

Tags: php

Увидел в книге такой метод в классе, для чего свойства обворачиваются в фигурные скобки?

```
function pechat(){
    echo "{$this->name} "."{$this->lastname}";
}
```

Comment: для того, чтобы понять,нужнва ли вам переменная $a с последующей стрелкой или свойство в записи `"$a->b"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При использовании двойных кавычек часто бывает, что переменную нужно использовать в чуть изменнёном виде. Но при анализе строки PHP не сможет определить, что это переменная. Для решения этой проблемы оберните переменную в фигурные скобки.

```
<?php
$juice = 'plum';
echo "I drank some juice made of $juices";    // $juices не определена

vs.

$juice = 'plum';
echo "I drank some juice made of {$juice}s";    // $juice будет анализирована.

/**
 * Комплексные переменные также оборачивайте в фигурные скобки.
 */

$juice = array('apple', 'orange', 'plum');
echo "I drank some juice made of {$juice[1]}s";   // $juice[1] будет анализирована.
```

Взято [тут](http://getjump.me/ru-php-the-right-way/pages/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B.html)

Тоже самое касается полей класов и методов гетеров

Тоесть если у Вас убрать кавычки то в лучшем случае(это если у Вас в класе определен метод [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)) Вы получите что то подобное

```
"строкаКоторуюВозвращает__toString->name строкаКоторуюВозвращает__toString->lastname"
```

В худшем случае - получите что то в стиле, а так будет скорей всего

> ErrorException Object of class ВашКласс could not be converted to string

И еще, раз Вы используете двойные квычки конкатенация излишня. Можно написать так:

```
echo "{$this->name} {$this->lastname}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Фигурные скобки нужны для группировки переменных. Как интерпретатор поймёт - это свойство класса или переменна, которую надо вывести перед строкой "->name"?

Это основа основ. Советую всегда сначала изучать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) и как минимум поискать перед тем, как задавать вопрос.